VSCode not resolving installed libraries
VSCode throws errors for both Matplotlib and numpy. Both are installed, I'm running the correct version of Python, and running the code in IDLE works fine. Python is not running virtual environment, and both libraries are installed for version I am running 3.12. Interpreter is selected as 3.12
I've tried to install both packages from the terminal, but it says both are installed:
pip install numpy
pip install matplotlib

This is my Python script:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

It gives me these errors in VS Code:
Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance
Import "matplotlib" could not be resolved from source Pylance

How can I get numpy and matplotlib to resolve correctly?

check the interpreter path within the vscode, also check the pip connected to which python versions by which pip

If you find a library in IDLE and not in VSCode, that means that you have 2 distinct installations of Python on your workstation. Maybe of the same version, but yet in distinct folders.
